# How to iterate over a SortedSet to modify items within

Tags: java, iterator, sortedset

lets say I have an List. There is no problem to modify list's item in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { list.get(i).setId(i); }
```

But I have a SortedSet instead of list. How can I do the same with it?
Thank you

Comment: This will only work if setId() doesn't alter a field used by compareTo().  Ideally, all the fields used by compareTo should be `final` and immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `Set` assumes that its elements are immutable (actually, mutable elements *are* permitted, but they must adhere to a very specific contract, which I doubt your class does).

This means that generally you can't modify a set element in-place like you're doing with the list.

The two basic operations that a `Set` supports are the addition and removal of elements. A modification can be thought of as a removal of the old element followed by the addition of the new one:

1. You can take care of the removals while you're iterating, by using [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29);
2. You could accumulate the additions in a separate container and call [`Set.addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) at the end.

Comment: He's not modifying the data structure..he's modifying the elements within while he iterates

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify set's key, because it causes the set rehasing/reordering. So, it will be undefined behaviour how the iteration will run further.

You could remove elements using iterator.remove(). But you cannot add elements, usually better solution is to accumulate them in a new collection and addAll it after the iteration.

```
Set mySet = ...;
ArrayList newElems = new ArrayList();

for(final Iterator it = mySet.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
{
  Object elem = it.next();
  if(...)
   newElems.add(...);
  else if(...)
   it.remove();
  ...
}
mySet.addAll(newElems);
```

Comment: If `id` isn't a field used in the comparator, it's safe to do.

Comment: @kan, He's not modifying the data structure..he's modifying the elements within while he iterates.

Comment: @Крысa Oh, right. Of course it's forbidden. If he need to change the id, he should `it.remove` the element, change the id and then `newElems.add`.

Comment: @Крысa: Kan's point is that if the class's equality is based on the ID (which is being changed), then the integrity of the data structure is compromised.

Comment: Yes, I've assumed that the `id` affects the collection's comparator. If it doesn't then there is no problem at all to use `setId` as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) or better still the enhanced for-loop syntax (which depends on the class implementing the [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface), irrespective of the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) you're using.  This abstracts away the mechanism used to traverse the collection and allows a new implementation to be substituted in without affecting the iteration routine.

For example:

```
Set<Foo> set = ...

// Enhanced for-loop syntax
for (Foo foo : set) {
 // ...
} 

// Iterator approach
Iterator it = set.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Foo foo = it.next();
}
```

**EDIT**

Kan makes a good point regarding modifying the item's key.  Assuming that your class's `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are based solely on the "id" attribute (which you're changing) the safest approach would be to explicitly remove these from the `Set` as you iterate and add them to an "output" `Set`; e.g.

```
SortedSet<Foo> input = ...
SortedSet<Foo> output = new TreeSet<Foo>();

Iterator<Foo> it = input.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Foo foo = it.next();
  it.remove(); // Remove from input set before updating ID.
  foo.setId(1);
  output.add(foo); // Add to output set.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 1.6, you're able to use a [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. But you may try, maybe you'll succeed, maybe you'll get `ConcurrentModificationException`. It's very important to remember, that modifying elements while iterating may have unexpected results. You should instead collect that elements in some collection. And after the iteration modify them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work, if `id` is not used for equals, or the comperator you used for the sorted set:

```
int counter = 0;
for(ElementFoo e : set) {
  e.setId(counter);
  couter++;
}
```

Comment: The OP isn't removing items from the list; they're merely calling a mutator on each object.

Comment: I don't need to remove the item. I have to update some fields. So the solution is to store new/updated/removed items in another list?