# Is it safe to add elements to a SortedSet while iterating

Tags: java, sortedset

Is it safe to add elements to a modifiable `SortedSet` while iterating over that set? In particular, is it safe to add elements to later in the set than the element indicated by the iterator?

For example, will the following code corrupt the `SortedSet s` or throw an exception (which would likely to be a `ConcurrentModificationException`):

```
 /**
  * s not null, is modifiable.
  */
 private final addSelectedFollowers(final SortedSet<Integer> s)
 {
    for (Integer i: s) {
       if (shouldAddNext(i)) {
          s.add(i + 1);
       }
    }
 }

 protected abstract boolean shouldAddNext(int i);
```

My guess is that it **is** safe, but I can't find a clear statement in the JRE API documentation. I know that if the behaviour is not specified, the implementation is free to decide upon the behaviour. Lack of an explicit statement in the documentation of `SortedSet` *is not enough* to answer the question one way or the other; the required behaviour might be specified indirectly, in the documentation for a different class or interface. The JRE documenters unfortunately do not always explicitly state what is permitted. I'm therefore looking for answers that reference the JRE API, rather than a bald assertion of *yes* or *no*. I also know that a `SortedSet` can be made [unmodifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010580/how-to-return-a-constant-collection), which would make the `SortedSet.add()` fail; I'm interested in the case of a modifiable `SortedSet`.

Note that I'm asking about adding elements to the set, not [modifying elements within the set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311011/how-to-iterate-over-a-sortedset-to-modify-items-within).

Comment: Depends upon which implementation of `SortedSet` it is. Just to pick on the known subclasses, `ConcurrentSkipListSet` wouldn't; `TreeSet` would.

Comment: @AndyTurner @fabian A programmer implementing a `class` that implements an `interface` must conform to the contract (specification) of all `interface`s and `classes` he/she uses. So it *does not* depend on the implementation, *if* the contracts (specifications) indicate can be satisfied only by an implementation that has the property I am interested in. The essence of my question is to find the part of the JRE specification that indicates that a `SortedSet` has that property, or to show how an implementation could fail to have that property and yet conform to the JRE specification.

Comment: @Raedwald and if the interface doesn't specify the behaviour, then it's up to the implementation to decide what they want to do.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is wrong to look at just the one interface (`SortedSet` here), because other interfaces are relevant (`Collection`, `Iterator`), and some information is implied (through clarification in a sub interface or implementing class).

Comment: @Raedwald if you think that the behaviour is specified one way or the other in `SortedSet` or in any of the interfaces it extends, please file a bug with Oracle, because `ConcurrentSkipListSet` and `TreeSet` clearly implement opposite behaviours.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right. Pointing out that `ConcurrentSkipListSet` and `TreeSet` clearly implement opposite behaviours **answers the question**.

Comment: @Raedwald I did point that out all along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the behaviour is not specified, the implementation is free to decide upon the behaviour.

For example, the two classes listed as known implementing classes in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implement both behaviours:

- [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html):

  > Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the set at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. **They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException**, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.
- [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

  > The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, **the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException**.

However, more fundamentally, [`Collection.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) (and [`Set.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))) is documented as an optional operation, so we can *never* rely upon a call to `SortedSet.add` being safe, whether in the context an ongoing iteration or not.

For instance, calling `add` on a `SortedSet` returned by [`Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSortedSet(java.util.SortedSet)) or a [Guava `ImmutableSortedSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html) would result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: "`Collection.add (and Set.add)` is documented as an optional operation", yes. Of course I am implicitly interested in the case of a modifiable sorted set [edited question to clarify].

Comment: @Raedwald How will you know whether it is a modifiable `SortedSet`?

Comment: For a `public` or `protected` context (method) you can require it to be modifiable in your API documentation. For a `private` context (method) or local context (local variable) you control everything.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the implementation. For example in case of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), iterators are *fail-fast*, therefore adding elements while iterating will trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From the JavaDoc of `TreeSet`:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Other implementations with non-fail-fast iterators may allow adding elements while iterating.